# NFT Rental Escrow and Uses

Tags: nft, program

Anyone familiar with NFT escrow programs? I have a business logic issue with a program. If I am sending an NFT to a vault to open an escrow to rent that NFT,  is it possible to still interact with that NFT. So for example this NFT is a season ticket with lets say 10 uses. I want to rent 2 event days of it to another user, so I put it up to rent in the vault, but I still have to use that NFT for my own events in the meantime, can this NFT still be used while in the vault?

Answer (score 0):

When you send the NFT to the vault then in this case the vault or the program becomes the owner of that NFT. I am not sure how the uses are going to be defined by you, but when you transfer the NFT you own into the vault and through the vault some other user is going to use it, make sure to delegate their token account to your program and freeze the token in their wallet. Otherwise the user renting it out can move it freely and the program won't have control over it.